# SAPUI5 navigation using browser or android back button

Tags: android, navigation, back-button, sapui5

My SAPUI5 app is working fine. The navigation using the navButton is ok. But within use navigation on browser or Android back button, the app navigate though the history.

How can I disable these navigation leaving only my app's navigation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no way you can disable the back button on a browser. You could however use the router mechanism and have hashes for your navigation, so these are stored in the browser history

Comment: Hi Qualiture, I'm using the router as you suggested, but my problem is, for e.g., when the user makes the logoff of my app, he is routed to Login page. So, when he uses the back button, he can back to the internal app pages. Is there a way to block these accesses? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Not with the back buttons, but your app pages should have a check whether a user is authenticated or not. So if a user is logged out, and uses the back button, the authorization check should regignize this and direct him to the login page again

Comment: I haver to do this in onInit function for eg?

Comment: It's a bit more than that... see this chapter https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?91f3d8706f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html

Comment: Qualiture, I'm not sure if this can help-me! It looks like to SAP platform only. And the SAPUI5 Security links didn't open.

Comment: How to check in which page the user is? Neither onInit or onBeforeRendering functions catch the information that the user enter on the page when using the browser/android nav buttons

Comment: If you don't use SAP platform, then you should take a look at the chapter before it: Securing HTML5 applications. But since you have login page, that also means you have some kind of backend session management (I hope!!) You should incorporate that in your pages (if Java based, you could use the security constraints and servlet filters in web.xml)

Comment: Really, if you're not using SAP platform, then it is just simply a matter of implementing the web security mechanisms for your application server platform

Comment: OK! But independent of platform, which function is called when I press the back button? Because, I already test the init, before rendering, after rendering and any one is called when back the previous page! I'm imagining that is in one of these functions that I have to test if the user is already logged. Right?

Comment: Euh, no... if the backbutton is pushed when a user is logged out, you **dont** want users to access your application pages at all. Therefore it is really up to the platform how to catch these requests, and gracefully directs the user to a login page

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. The user can't access my app without authenticate again. But what I want to know is, how can I block the user, or better, how can I know that the user is on a internal page? If I can check in which page the user is, I can check if he is authenticated on my server.

Comment: **No, you should not check inside your application pages, that is too late!** Your user is then already "in" your application! You should check on web application level. See for instance http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-web-application-security on how to protect your web application on Java platform